# Unable to run object’s function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am trying to run a function of an object created using a constructor function. However, I am unable to do so as I keep getting and error saying “TypeError: mutant_cat.meow is not a function. (In 'mutant_cat.meow()', 'mutant_cat.meow' is undefined)”. 
This is my constructor function:

```js
function Cat(legs, sound) {
    this.legs = legs;
    this.sound = sound;
    var meow = function() {
        document.write(sound);
    }
}
```

And this is where I create the object and attempt to run its function:

```js
var mutant_cat = new Cat(5, "eeeeeee");
mutant_cat.meow();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need `meow` to be on `this`: `this.meow =` Better yet, put it on the prototype: `Cat.prototype.meow = `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it. You need to have the function be a property of the object by using "this".

```
function Cat(legs, sound) {
    this.legs = legs;
    this.sound = sound;
    this.meow = () => {
        document.write(this.sound);
    }
}
```

If you expect all your Cats to meow then you are better off using a prototype function as this is memory optimized and a shared function between all Cat instances rather than each Cat having its own duplicate meow function.

You can read more about prototype functions here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

Answer (score 2):

It's considered better practice to define your method on the prototype outside the constructor. This way we dont have to define the function for each instance of `Cat`:

```js
function Cat(legs, sound) {
  this.legs = legs;
  this.sound = sound;
}

//Add the method to the protoype instead of constructor
Cat.prototype.meow = function() {
  console.log(this.sound);
}

var mutant_cat = new Cat(5, "eeeeeee");
mutant_cat.meow();
```